# How to find the number of Flower objects in a grid?

Tags: java, object, gridworld

First off, I am very sorry about the way I am asking this question. This came up on a practice review my class is doing, and I have no idea really what its asking for or how to begin. Here is the question:

A Grid object in GridWorld has getNumRows and getNumCols methods, which return the number of rows and the number of columns in the grid, respectively. A Grid object also has a method get(Location, loc), which returns the actor at location loc, or null, if the location is unoccupied. Write a method that returns the number of Flower objects in grid.

Any push in the right direction would be great, once again sorry how poorly this is being asked. 
Thank you.

Comment: Without some code it is hard to understand what you want/need to do.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you mean this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GridWorld

Comment: @Jocob Kudria Yes, I am Talking about Gridworld.

Comment: It looks like, given some kind of object representing a grid (as in, a 2d area with coordinates--think graph paper), you're supposed to look at each set of coordinates, find out if there's a "Flower" object there, and count up how many total "Flower" objects you find. You should only need the four methods you're given to make your new method (call it "getNumFlowers", for instance). Does all of that make sense?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but can't you just iterate through each cell in the grid and check if there is a Flower object there?

Comment: This somehow brings the Terrarium in the book Eloquent Javascript to mind.

Comment: I think if iterating/counting seemed like a basic operation to the asker, the question would seem more straightforward to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this is probably what you are looking for. Not sure about the correctness of the program as I'm not familiar with GridWorld or the other objects in your code.

The basics are however the double loop, looping over each row and for each row looping over the column thus covering the whole grid.

As you can see I left the `isFlowerAt` method empty since I have no idea what `grid.get()` will return.

```
int counter = 0;
for (int row  = 0; row < grid.getNumRows(); row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < grid.getNumCols(); col++) {
        if (isFlowerAt(grid, row, col)){
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
return counter;

private boolean isFlowerAt(Grid grid, int row, int col) {
    //Return true if a flower is located at (row, col)
}
```

Comment: For the isFlowerAt method, simply use get(Location loc) method. "loc" will be the location at which you are at - it will return Flower or something else. I might have not made sense...

Comment: Could be a `String` with "flower" as the content, an enum or an object. Hence why I didn't fill it out. This does however seem to be a school assignment so it doesnt hurt to like some blanks.

Comment: It's still possible to do the check with all those cases. But leaving blanks is always good - leaves space for fun.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of implementing it:

```
public class Grid {

private int numRows;
private int numCols;
private List<Location> locations;

public Grid() {
    this.locations = new ArrayList<Location>();
}

public Flower get(Location loc) {
    Flower flower = null;
    for(Location location: locations) {
        if(location.getRowValue() == loc.getRowValue() 
                && location.getColValue() == loc.getColValue()) {
            flower = location.getFlower();
            break;
        }
    }
    return flower;
}

public int getTotalFlowers() {
    int total = 0;
    for(Location location: locations) {
        if(location.getFlower()!=null) {
            total++; 
        }
    }
    return total;
}

// ... put your getters and setters here

}
```

And here's the Location class

```
public class Location {

private int rowValue;
private int colValue;
private Flower flower;

// ... put your getters and setters here

}
```

It is assumed that you would be populating the grid with Locations and some of those locations will have flowers and some won't.